# Paypal IPN : log for manual investigation

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, paypal, paypal-ipn

In [paypal's IPN sample code for PHP5.2](https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623), on the last lines, they got a comment to "log for manual investigation".

```
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
```

What kind of info should I log and how ?

Comment: Try to be more specific. Which sample code? Can you paste it? Or where did you find it? Where is the "place to see if the call to the script came from paypal" ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question with the info you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to log the answer you got from paypal via the $_POST vars.

If you use a framework or CMS it might have a logging function. Otherwise you can use PHP's `error_log` function

For example:

```
$post_vars = var_export($_POST, true);
error_log("IPN Result: " . $res, 3, "/var/tmp/ipn.log");
error_log("POST_VARS: " . $post_vars, 3, "/var/tmp/ipn.log");
```

Where /var/tmp/ipn.log is a custom path where your log file should appear.

Comment: I'm using expressionengine, (based on codeigniter), so yes, I think it might have a logging function. I'll do my homework and read the docs. Thank you.